# Transfer data from pdf to Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I have a working code to transfer data from a pdf to a S/S, but have one issue. I want the code to proceed through the pdf pages and stop at the end. The problem is in how to get the process to recognize the page being displayed in the pdf:

```
  Sub Trial()

Dim adobeReaderPath As String
Dim pathAndFileName As String
Dim shellPathName As String
Dim lastrow4 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim displaypage As Integer

   pathAndFileName = "C:\New Folder\2002.pdf"
   adobeReaderPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
   shellPathName = adobeReaderPath & " """ & pathAndFileName & """"
   Call Shell( _
    pathname:=shellPathName, _
    windowstyle:=vbNormalFocus)
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
    SendKeys "^a"
    SendKeys "^c"
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Range("A1").Select
        ws.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
    SendKeys "^{PGDN}"


  'the problem starts here  there is no recognition of the display page number and it moves to the else part

  If displaypage = 2 Then
    SendKeys "^a"
    SendKeys "^c"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    lastrow4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & lastrow4 + 1).Select
    ws.Paste
  Else
    SendKeys "^q"
    End If
```

It works fine if I leave out the "dispalaypage" if/then sequence and use a set number of pdf pages, but I want it open ended so I can format it for any size document and have it stop when it finishes with all the pages. I don't need the do until or loop parts, I just need to know how to set up the thing to recognize which page the pdf is on so it will move through the If sequence correctly. 
Thanks,
E.T.

Comment: I was able to adapt this code to use. Maybe someone else can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adapt this code to my use. Perhaps others can use it as well.

`Sub Test()
    Dim MyPath As String, MyFile As String
    Dim i As Long
    MyPath = "C:\New Folder"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & Application.PathSeparator & "*.pdf", vbDirectory)
    Range("A:B").ClearContents
    Range("A1") = "File Name": Range("B1") = "Pages"
    Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    i = 1
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 1) = MyFile
        Cells(i, 2) = GetPageNum(MyPath & Application.PathSeparator & MyFile)
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    MsgBox "Total of " & i - 1 & " PDF files have been found" & vbCrLf _
           & " File names and corresponding count of pages have been written on " _
           & ActiveSheet.Name, vbInformation, "Report..."
End Sub
'
Function GetPageNum(PDF_File As String)
    'Haluk 19/10/2008
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim strRetVal As String
    Dim RegExp
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    RegExp.Global = True
    RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]"
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open PDF_File For Binary As #FileNum
        strRetVal = Space(LOF(FileNum))
        Get #FileNum, , strRetVal
    Close #FileNum
    GetPageNum = RegExp.Execute(strRetVal).Count
End Function`